# How to unzip multiple dataframes from a json dump into Pandas dataframes

Tags: python, json, pandas

I stored two dataframes into json as such

```
df_json= {
    'df1': df1.to_json(orient='split'),
    'df2': df2.to_json(orient='split')
}
df_dump = json.dumps(df_json)
```

Now I want to read my df_dump that has the two dataframes and store each one in an individual dataframe

```
df_1_extract = 'df1'
df_2_extract = 'df2'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, try:

```
df_dict = json.loads(df_dump)
df_1_extract = pd.read_json(df_dict["df1"], orient="split")
df_2_extract = pd.read_json(df_dict["df2"], orient="split")
```